Justify True or False A monotonic sequence can at most have one limit point
Definition: For $S\subset\mathbb{R},\ a\in\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a limit point of $S$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $a$ contains infinitely many points of the set $S.$
Justify True or False: A monotonic sequence can at most have one limit point.
It seems true intuitively since if a monotonic sequence converges has a unique limit but is it true for limit point as well.

For the bounded case see here.

Thankyou, but what is the case for an unbounded monotonic sequence,can I consider two limit points and show that both are also the limit of the sequence which yeilds a contradiction

If it diverges it may have more than one limit points so the case must be for a convergent sequence

More than one limit point? Do you have an example? Remember, monotonic divergent.

A divergent sequence has no limit but I can't say for limit point

What is the definition of limit point you are working with?

S a subset of R , a belonging to R a is said to be a limit point of S if for every epsilon>0 the epsilon neighborhood of a contains infinitely many points of the set S

That's an overkill (but correct) definition btw. Not your fault, I'm guessing it's from your lecture notes or whatever book you're working from. A more standard definition is: For $S\subset\mathbb{R},\ a\in\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a limit point of $S$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $a$ contains a point of $S$ different from $a.$

Isn't that the one of accumulation point

Accumulation point and limit point are synonyms.

Suppose the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is monotonic and non-decreasing. There are two possibilities: either there exists an upper bound on the values on $\{f_{n}\}$, or not. If there exists an upper bound on $f_{n}$, a theorem taught in every Calculus 101 course states that $\{f_{n}\}$ has a limit, and it is trivial to show that, if a sequence has a limit, it is the only limit point of this sequence (proof from contradiction: suppose there were two limit points, $x, x'$ and consider $\varepsilon < |x-x'|/2$). At the other hand, suppose $f_{n}$ is non-decreasing and not bound from above. This means, by definition, that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists n\in \mathbb{N}: \forall N > n: f_{N} \ge x$. Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ was a limit point. Then an infinite number of terms of $\{ f_{n} \}$ would lie in every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$. But from the definition of unboundedness from above and from the definition of non-decreasing sequence, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}: \forall N > n: f_{N} \ge x + \varepsilon$, hence, only a finite number of terms lies in every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ for every finite $x$.

Suppose $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a monotone sequence of real numbers. Suppose it is non-decreasing (the proof for non-increasing is similar).
If $a_n$ is bounded then it is bounded above, and so the link in the comments shows that there is only one limit point.
So from now on, consider the other case: $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded. Then since it is non-decreasing, it must be unbounded above. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then $\exists\ N$ such that $a_n>a+1\ \forall\ n\geq N.$ Therefore $a$ is not a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty},$ because the $\varepsilon-$ neighbourhood $(a-1,a+1)$ of $a$ contains at most $N-1$ members of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty},$ and therefore does not contain infinitely many members of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Therefore $a$ is not a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Since this is true for all $a\in\mathbb{R},$ it follows that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has no limit points.

Notations: I will use $s_i$ for the i-th term of the sequence.
I shall assume here that the sequence is non decreasing. If it was non decreasing, I would study the sequence $-s_n$ which would be non decreasing.
Let us assume that the sequence has one limit point $L$ and one value strictly greater than $L$:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \forall N\in \Bbb N, \exists n>N / |s_n-L| < \varepsilon$$
$$\exists M\in\Bbb N, s_M>L$$
For $\varepsilon = \frac{s_M-L} 2$, we have $\forall n>M, s_n\ge s_M>L+\varepsilon$. Which means that $L$ cannot be a limit point.
So we have showned that if a non decreasing sequence admits at least one limit point, it is bounded by that limit point.
If a distinct limit point $L_1$ existed, it should be smaller than $L$: $L_1<L$. But if $L_1$ is a limit point then we should also have $L<L_1$, which is a contradiction.
So a non decreasing sequence can only have one limit point.
